Mostrar etiqueta valor en grafica Potly
Hola a todos estoy usando unas graficas de la libreria potly y funciona bien, pero como hago para que en la grafica se muestre la etiqueta del valor en el mismo grafico y no tener que poner el mouse sobre el nodo para que este aparezca...

He leido sobre esto pero no se como aplicarlo a mi grafico...


$conexion=conexion();
//seleccionamos los valores de la tabla segun criterio que necesitemos
$sql="SELECT fecha, neto, conductor, municipio, quedia, empresa, placa FROM basculas WHERE fecha BETWEEN '$fecha22w' AND '$fecha33w' AND placa='$placaw' ORDER BY fecha";
// almacenamos resultados 
$result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
// creamos variables para arreglos
$valoresY=array(); //neto
$valoresX=array(); //fecha
//$conductorA=array(); //Conductor
//$municipioA=array(); //Municipio
//obtenemos los datos y los almacensmosen arreglo
while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$valoresX[]=$ver[0];
$valoresY[]=$ver[1];
$conductorA[]=$ver[2];
$municipioA[]=$ver[3];
$quediaA[]=$ver[4];
$empresaA[]=$ver[5];
$placaA[]=$ver[6];
}
//pasamos el array o arreglo a cadena json
$datosX=json_encode($valoresX);
$datosY=json_encode($valoresY);
$conductor=json_encode($conductorA);
$municipio=json_encode($municipioA);
$quedia=json_encode($quediaA);
$empresa=json_encode($empresaA);
$placa=json_encode($placaA);
$datosY=str_replace(".","","$datosY");
?>
<div id="graficolineal"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function crearCadenaLineal(json){
var parsed=JSON.parse(json);
var arr=[];
for(var x in parsed){
    arr.push(parsed[x]);
}
return arr;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
datosX=crearCadenaLineal('<?php echo $datosX ?>');
datosY=crearCadenaLineal('<?php echo $datosY ?>');
municipioLL=<?php echo $municipio ?>;
conductorLL=<?php echo $conductor ?>;
quediaLL=<?php echo $quedia ?>;
empresaLL=<?php echo $empresa ?>;
placaLL=<?php echo $placa ?>;
<?php
if($tip=="Conductor"){
    $varseleccion="conductorLL";
}else if ($tip=="Municipio"){
    $varseleccion="municipioLL";
}else if ($tip=="Dia"){
    $varseleccion="quediaLL";
}else if ($tip=="Empresa"){
    $varseleccion="empresaLL";
}else if ($tip=="Placa"){
    $varseleccion="placaLL";
}
?>
//------------------------------------
var trace1 = {
  x: datosX,
  y: datosY, 
   type: 'scatter',
   line: {
 color:'<?php echo $colorw ?>',
 width:0.8  
 },
 text: <?php echo $varseleccion ?>,
 marker:{
 color:'<?php echo $colorpw ?>',
 size:6
 }
}
var layout={
    title: 'Gráfica Disposición en Relleno Vehículo Placa <?=$placaw?> Fecha <?=$fecha22w?>  a  <?=$fecha33w?>',
xaxis:{
    title:'Fecha'   
},
yaxis:{
title: 'Neto'
}
};

var data = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('graficolineal', data, layout);
</script>




Suponiendo que estas utilizando la última versión de Plotly, para visualizar el valor de cada punto en el gráfico tenes que agregar en mode el valor text.
Ejemplo:
mode: 'lines+markers+text',

Demo


var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2],
  y: [1, 2, 4],
  mode: 'lines+markers+text', // <- ACA
  name: 'Lines, Markers and Text',
  text: ['Text A', 'Text B', 'Text C'],
  textposition: 'top',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1];
var layout = {showlegend: false};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.6.3.min.js'></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>




Referencia:

Plotly > JavaScript > Fundamentals > Text and Annotations


Hola Marcos mil gracias por tu respuesta, uso la versión plotly-2.6.3.min.js y no veo en esa parte donde ponerle el TEXT que me dices

Hola @Eduardo, actualice mi respuesta, espero ahora esté más visible. Saludos!

FUNCIONA PERFECTOOOOOOO MIL GRACIAS!!!!
